# Repeatedly having to install xcode for git

Tags: xcode, git

Whenever I try to run `git init` I keep getting the error

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I can fix this by running

`xcode-select --install`

However next time I come to making a new git repo, I get the same error and have to run the command again. Is there someway I can persist this so I dont have to reinstall xcode everytime

Comment: If you don’t want to install Xcode, use homebrew to install git. But you will still need the command line tools.

Comment: @matt I dont mind installing xcode, I just dont want to have to install it everytime I start a new git repo. Git is already installed via homebrew

Comment: Then you are apparently not _using_ the Git installed by homebrew. (And `xcode-select --install` does not install Xcode.)